# I want a trigger to change case status to close if it satisfies the conditions

Tags: apex, trigger, string

I wrote a trigger to change case status to close if case is from specific email address and if the subject has a word from a list of word from custom label (Sub).

I want the subject to be converted to uppercase, as custom label has all uppercase words, but I am getting null pointer exception while doing it and also for `if(clist.Subject.toUpperCase() == label)`.

Below is the handler class code. Can anyone help me on this?

```java
public class CloseHandler1 {
    public static void methodClose(List<Case> caseList){
        List<EmailMessage> Emsg = new List<EmailMessage>();
        Emsg = [SELECT FromAddress FROM EmailMessage WHERE ParentId IN :caseList];
  
        List<String> words = System.Label.Sub.split(', ');
        List<Case> updatedCase = new List<Case>();
    
        try{
            for (EmailMessage msg : Emsg){ 
                if(msg.FromAddress == 'xyz@gmail.com'){ 
                    for(Case clist : caseList){
                        for(String label : words){
                            if(clist.Subject.toUpperCase() == label){
                                clist.Status = 'closed';
                                updatedCase.add(clist);
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                }
                else if (msg.FromAddress == 'abcdw@gmail.com'){
                    for(Case clist : caseList){
                        for(String label : words){
                            if(clist.Subject.toUpperCase() == label){
                                clist.Status='closed';
                                updatedCase.add(clist);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(DmlException e) {
            System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
        }  

        if (!updatedCase.isEmpty()){
            update updatedCase;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### A few notes to start things off

- Your try/catch in this code should be removed
- There is no need to check if `updatedCase` is empty before performing DML on it

It is impossible for the code in your try/catch block to throw a DML Exception (because there's no DML being performed in that block). Even if you change that to a more appropriate exception type, swallowing exceptions (i.e. doing nothing with the exception. Printing the exception to the log is not sufficient.) is very bad practice. I'd go so far as to say it's an anti-pattern. Leaving this in will make it much harder to debug/maintain this code.

As for the DML at the end, Salesforce is kind enough to perform an implicit check to see if the list is empty. If it is empty, the DML statement won't be run and it won't count against the DML Statement governor limit. So there's no need for you to explicitly check this.

#### Moving onto the main portion

You haven't given us the exact error message, and don't indicate what line it happens on. If you are facing a Null Pointer Exception though, there are only 3 places in your code where it could happen.

- `List<String> words = System.Label.Sub.split(', ');`
- The two instances of `if(clist.Subject.toUpperCase() == label){`

I'll assume that your label does actually have data in it, meaning that the issue is that one of your cases does not have a subject.

You'll need to guard against the possibility of a null Subject value. The easiest way to do that being to use the Safe Navigation Operator `?.`

So instead of `if(clist.Subject.toUpperCase() == label){`
you'd use `if(clist.Subject?.toUpperCase() == label){`

If the left-hand side of the operator evaluates to null, it causes Salesforce to not evaluate the right-hand side of the operator. A null subject would cause the statement to partially evaluate to `if(null == label){`, which does not present any issues.

#### There are more issues with your code

The triple nested loop here is very inefficient.
Why do you need to upper-case the subject inside of the `for(String label : words){` loop? the subject will never change in that innermost loop.

Why do you need to literally copy and paste the code for the second target email address?

Worse than that though, you're not making sure that the email with one of your target addresses is related to the case you're currently processing. If *any* case has an email message with one of your target addresses, then *all* cases with a subject matching your word list will get closed.

By taking a step back, and dedicating some time to think about what data you're working with, it's possible to make this code much more efficient, much shorter, and more correct (i.e. to actually do what you are trying to achieve).

- `EmailMessage` has the `ParentId` field, which is a relationship to a particular Case. In your query, you can fetch data from this relationship.
- You can use your target email addresses in a filter for your `EmailMessage` query to remove data that isn't important (instead of performing that filtering later using Apex)
- Instead of looping over each string in your word list and checking for equality, you can use a `Set<String>`

An example to help you along

```java
// The set constructor can take a list
// String's split() method returns a list
Set<String> targetWords = new Set<String>(System.label.myLabel.split(','));

// Maps are good at preventing duplicate items from being stored (helps avoid
//   "duplicate item in list" errors when performing DML)
Map<Id, Account> accountToUpdateMap = new Map<Id, Account>();

// Sets are very good (and very quick)for figuring out if a piece (or pieces //   of) data exists
Set<String> targetOppOwnerNames = new Set<String>{'John Doe', 'Joe Nobody'};

// Querying for parent data can be helpful (you could also use a parent-child
//   subquery instead)
// Filtering data in a query is usually preferable to doing it in Apex
for(Opportunity opp :[SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Owner.Name IN :targetOppOwnerNames]){
    // By using a set instead of a list, we can avoid a nested loop
    if(targetWords.contains(opp.Account.Name?.toUpperCase())){
        // If there's already data for the given account id in the map, we'll
        //   simply replace the data in the map (instead of getting duplicate data)
        accountToUpdateMap.put(opp.AccountId, new Account(
            // The only thing we need to be able to update an SObject record
            //   is the record Id
            Id = opp.AccountId,
            Custom_Status__c = 'Key Account - Active'
        ));
    }
}

// We can't call update a map directly, but we can call update on the result of
//   .values() (if the map's value type is an SObject and not a collection of 
//   sobjects)
update accountToUpdateMap.values();
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `==` is case insensitive for string comparisons; you don't need to use `toUpperCase()` in your code. However, in my modified example, we'll be using it for efficiency by checking values in a `Set`.

Second, you should be using a Map for efficiency of finding the parent case.

Third, your code should stop after finding a matching word, because otherwise you might add the case more than once.

Fourth, you're duplicating code unnecessarily. You can use the OR operator to make your code more efficient, or even use a more efficient method of checking the email with a list or set.

Fifth, you don't need the try-catch block, you need better logic.

Sixth, you don't need to check if a list is empty before performing DML on it.

Seventh, your code will end up closing records unintentionally in bulk updates, even if they don't meet the criteria, because you're not concerned about if the email message is from a particular case or not.

Eighth, if you do this in a "before" trigger, you can avoid the DML. Consider doing this if possible. I'll assume that, for sake of argument, that this cannot be done, but you should investigate this.

Ninth, there might be multiple matching emails for one parent case, so we want to avoid duplicate updates. We'll use a map for this.

Tenth, we can make the code more efficient by filtering the email messages by FromAddress.

Eleventh, we can use `?.` as a means of avoiding null pointer exceptions. This strictly shouldn't be necessary in our code, but it's also harmless, so we'll use it anyways.

Twelfth, we'll make sure the case isn't already closed before we close it, so we don't end up in an infinite loop.

Applying all this, we end up with:

---

```
public class CloseHandler1 {
    public static void methodClose(List<Case> caseList){
        Set<String> fromAddresses = new Set<String>{'xyz@gmail.com','abcdw@gmail.com'};
        List<EmailMessage> Emsg = [SELECT ParentId FROM EmailMessage WHERE ParentId IN :caseList AND FromAddress = :fromAddresses];
        Set<String> words = new Set<String>(System.Label.Sub.toUpperCase().split(', *'));
        Map<Id, Case> casesById = new Map<Id, Case>(caseList);
        Map<Id, Case> updatedCase = new Map<Id, Case>();

        for(EmailMessage email: Emsg) {
            Case caseRecord = casesById.get(email.ParentId);
            if(words.contains(caseRecord.Subject?.toUpperCase()) && caseRecord.Status != 'Closed') {
                updatedCase.add(new Case(Id=caseRecord.Id, Status='Closed'));
            }
        }
        update updatedCase.values();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want this trigger to execute before insert, as in before insert we don't have Ids. how can I link a Case record to a EmailMessage record (as  it is trigger which runs on email-to-case records). Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: @sravanthim A child cannot exist before its parent. No email message will exist for a case in a `before insert` or `after insert` trigger.

Comment: In Email-to-Case we have a queue which will be the owner of the case if email is sent to specific address of org. example if email sent to abc@gmail.com, owner will be abc queue or if email sent to xyz@gmail.com, owner will be zyx queue.
 Is the Case Owner field available in before insert?

Comment: even if the owner is available can I hardcode queue id in trigger?